# Identify computer seen in Wikipedia

Tags: identify-this-computer

I remember browsing in WikiPedia a year or two ago and found an interesting old computer running some UNIX or similar os, where the screenshot of the terminal was amusing because it was a computer or an account named my family name or very close to my family name ("Rosen*****"). I try to find which one it was but today having looked through all the VAX, VMS and PDP articles in Wikipedia I cannot find the one I was looking for. I'm quite sure that it was a system from 1970s or early 1980s where it was clearly seen from the screenshot of the terminal that the name of the machine was "Rosen****", Rosenholz or similar. I would like to find it if possible.

Comment: One of the principle designers of [_this_ interesting old computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERQ) has the surname, "Rosen." At least three different operating systems were developed for the computer, and one of those was Unix-like; But Mr. Rosen's name does not appear in the only screenshot in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: If  I had two computers I might call them Rosencrantz and Guildenstern...

Comment: @another-dave Maybe that was the real case. I'm sure there was such a screenshot of a vintage Unix system in Wikipedia but now I checked 42 of them and cannot find the one

Comment: @another-dave Found it! https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/OpenVMSlogin.png

Comment: I'm gratified my smart-aleck remark worked out for you!

Answer (score 5):

Found it! "Welcome to Rosencrantz!" If this is Rosencrantz, where is Guildenstern? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/OpenVMSlogin.png

[image]

Comment: Rosencrantz and Guildenstern were dead, but Rosencrantz was resurrected?

Comment: @MichaelGraf surely rebooted?? :)

Comment: @MichaelGraf It's a real family name in Denmark, Norway and Sweden and we are not fictional characters if I understand it correctly.

Comment: BTW, the [Living Computer Museum](https://livingcomputers.org/) unfortunately has been closed (maybe permanently), and at least some people working there have been laid off. A real loss.

Comment: "Unix or similar" - you just about got away with that, given "*several common Unix and MS-DOS commands have been aliased for your convenience.*"...

Comment: @NiklasR.— Yes, of course. That's why (as far as I understand it) Shakespeare chose these names, to add some authentic Danish flavour to _Hamlet, Prince of Denmark_. They then got remixed - hundreds of years later - into Stoppard's play _Rosencrantz and Guildenstern Are Dead_, which is what I was jokingly referring to.

Comment: *If this is Rosencrantz, where is Guildenstern?* - It was common practice among DEC sysadmins to add machines to the network in small load-sharing groups, and give the nodes in a group theme-associated names. *Rosencrantz* was almost certainly once half of a pair of 780s so named.